# C++ How do I Handle all possible Player Movement inputs?

Tags: c++

I am trying to clean up movement code I followed from a video tutorial series that was never finished. My intent is for the character to only ever be able to move on X or Y at any given time (so no diagonal). The character has direction facing to keep in mind.

My issue is the player can still press any key they want, or accidently press two keys at the same time.

Ex. if you move Up and make a right turn, accidentally press Right before letting go of Up.

Or if you press Up, press and let go Right to make a slight movement right while continuing to press Up, the player should continue to move up after letting go of Right without having to re-press Up. etc.

Just to make sure all possible input cases are handled intuitively.

EDIT: This is the code so far and I'm getting weird errors I don't know what's wrong

```
#pragma once
#include "../game.h"
#include "ECS.h"
#include "Components.h"
#include <list>

using namespace std;




class KeyboardController : public Component
{
public:
    TransformComponent *transform;
    SpriteComponent *sprite;

    std::list<SDL_Event> keyDownList;
    SDL_Event lastDirection;

    void updateKeyState()
    {
        if (Game::event.type == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
            Game::isRunning = false;
        }
        else if (Game::event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            keyDownList.push_back(Game::event.key.keysym.sym);
        }
        else if (Game::event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
            keyDownList.remove(Game::event.key.keysym.sym);
        }
    }

    void init() override
    {
        transform = &entity->getComponent<TransformComponent>();
        sprite = &entity->getComponent<SpriteComponent>();






    }




    void update() override
    {
        void updateKeyState();
        void updateMovement();

    }



};
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::list<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=SDL_Event, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list Sandbox C:\file_path\KeyboardController.h   31

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "SDL_Keycode" to "SDL_Event" Sandbox C:\file_path\KeyboardController.h   34

Comment: Separate the game logic out of the input logic. Let input be written to a `std::vector` of key states/history and use that as the basis of your game logic.

Comment: do you know where i can learn about this? The tutorial guy said he would go over states but has been gone for 6 months

Comment: I have no idea. Do note asking for tutorials is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should basically clean up your code by separating the logic between key events and player movement. So your `update()` method could look like this:

```
void update() override
{
    updateKeyState();
    updateMovement();
}
```

Since you want the player to move only vertically or horizontally (never diagonally), you have to store the key press order in a data structure that can be easily accessed. I think you could use a [doubly-linked list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list):

```
std::list<SDL_Event> keyDownList;
```

and we should also store the last key pressed in order to restore the idle animation of the player:

```
SDL_Event lastDirection;
```

The **`updateKeyState()`** method should add or remove the key to/from the linked list. We should also check if the player wants to leave the game by pressing `ESC`:

```
void updateKeyState() {
    if (Game::event.type == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
        Game::isRunning = false;
    } else if (Game::event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        keyDownList.push_back(Game::event.key.keysym.sym);
    } else if (Game::event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
        keyDownList.remove(Game::event.key.keysym.sym);
    }
}
```

The **`updatePlayerMovement()`** method is where the magic happens. We should basically check which key was pressed first and update the player position accordingly. We also save the down key in the `lastDirection` field in order to use it when no key is pressed.

```
void updateMovement() {
    // if any key is down
    if (keyDownList.size() > 0) {
        const SDL_Event downKey = keyDownList.front();
        switch (downKey) {
            case SDLK_w:
                transform->velocity.y = -1;
                transform->velocity.x = 0;
                sprite->Play("BackWalk");
                lastDirection = downKey;
                break;
            case SDLK_a:
                transform->velocity.x = -1;
                transform->velocity.y = 0;
                sprite->Play("SideWalk");
                sprite->spriteFlip = SDL_FLIP_HORIZONTAL;
                lastDirection = downKey;
                break;
            case SDLK_s:
                transform->velocity.y = 1;
                transform->velocity.x = 0;
                sprite->Play("FrontWalk");
                lastDirection = downKey;
                break;
            case SDLK_d:
                transform->velocity.x = 1;
                transform->velocity.y = 0;
                sprite->Play("SideWalk");
                sprite->spriteFlip = SDL_FLIP_NONE;
                lastDirection = downKey;
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // no key is down, handle idle situations
        transform->velocity.x= 0;
        transform->velocity.y = 0;

        switch (lastDirection) {
            case SDLK_w:
                sprite->Play("BackIdle");
                break;
            case SDLK_a:
                sprite->Play("SideIdle");
                break;
            case SDLK_s:
                sprite->Play("FrontIdle");
                break;
            case SDLK_d:
                sprite->Play("SideIdle");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this code because I don't have the code and structures from your game. So you may have to edit a piece here and there to make it work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out after some sleep

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Visual C++ STudio is telling me that on the curly brace after void updateKeyState() {  <-- right there, it tells me a semi-colon is expected

Comment: The problem is certainly somewhere else. If you remove the `updateKeyState()` member function and its call, does the code compile?

Comment: I have the function in void update() override but i'm not sure what a member function or call is,

Comment: everything is fine if I type updateKeyState();   but if I try to type the function updateKeyState(){} I get an error expecting a ; where the curly-braces are

Comment: In this case you should try declaring the member methods outside the class scope. There is an example here (look for the Rectangle class): http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Do you see what's wrong with this (code file)? [link](https://mega.nz/#!GzpTQIib!IIAgyrzLZg42SO9a9wO4Fmkg6gfnMZics4Id5hBjLQ4_)  I included the errors i'm getting in the original post

Comment: Inside the `update() {...}` method you have two `void` keywords and that's wrong. You should remove the `void`.

Comment: I fixed that and I am still getting a bunch of errors on lots of lines in the void updateKeyStates and void updateMovement functions, like line 42 there is an error on the period between keyDownList and push_back saying "no suitable constructor exists to convert from "SDL_Keycode" to "SDL_Event"

Comment: So `SDL_Keycode` is probably what you need. Replace `SDL_Event` with `SDL_Keycode` and check what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, this solved my issue but the journey continues